# Android google maps API Demos

Tags: android, google-maps

I have already checked 10 ways why wouldn't simple application which using google maps work but i don't have any right solution. I also tried to run sample which is located in ...\android-sdks\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps and it doesn't work. I just copy and paste all source code.

So my problem is that when i start the app it only shows light-brown background and google-maps zoom (+ and -). In "LogCat" i get error "Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors)."

...I have turn on wi-fi (network) ...i am pretty sure because some apps have been updated.

Comment: i had the same problem, check this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875590/google-maps-api-cannot-retrieve-ui/37875857#37875857

Answer (score 1):

"This is probably an authentication issue" sometimes means that your Maps V2 API key is incorrect, such as:

- You did not change what was in the project, or
- You did not use the right signing key when registering to have your Maps V2 API key in the Google APIs Console, or
- You used the wrong package name when registering to have your Maps V2 API key in the Google APIs Console

Comment: Tell me if i can use google-maps sample under android-skd directory  with existing APIkey which is use in sample ...i did not edit any code from sample ...also package name is the same
Or in my case, in my own app i generate sha-1 finger print at the beginning of project(i also regenerate it later and i got the same sha-1 print) which i put intu google api console with defenitly correct package name ...for google sample would be com.example.mapdemo

Comment: @rikkima: "Tell me if i can use google-maps sample under android-skd directory with existing APIkey which is use in sample" -- no. You need to use your own Maps V2 API key, for your own signing key.

Comment: It is the same...
HOW I GET FINGERPRINT
1) export aplication to get maps.keystore
2) in cmd run this "keytool -v -list -keystore maps.keystore"
3) next to sha-1: mark and copy
4) open google console and click create new Android key and past sha-1 pingerprint looks like "9C:XX:35:XX:60:XX:4E:XX:1F:XX:14:XX:00:XX:BE:5E:1F:96:8F:E6;com.example.mapdemo" (except Xs)

Is it right ?

Comment: @rikkima: I have no idea what you are referring to with step #1. Use your `debug.keystore`.