# Google Maps API cannot retrieve UI

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to build a google maps app. The app runs but I am unable to retrieve the map UI.

Logs shows :Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
06-16 22:45:50.480 13860-14718/com.mapsapi.vatsan.googlemapsapidemo E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                                                               Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                                                               Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                                                API Key: **************************************
                                                                                                Android Application (;): 24:85:5A:C0:F8:0D:36:4C:1A:B9:45:B6:21:92:B0:6E:7D:71:55:08;com.mapsapi.vatsan.googlemapsapidemo

I have used the correct API Key.

What exactly i have to do?﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there are diferent keys for debug and released apps.
i recomend API v3 too.

Try this to register your api key.

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=24:85:5A:C0:F8:0D:36:4C:1A:B9:45:B6:21:92:B0:6E:7D:71:55:08%3Bcom.mapsapi.vatsan.googlemapsapidemo
It can take some minutes. Then you have to set your google_maps_key in your android app Manifiest.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSDSSDDDAAD...Your API KEY" />
```

If doesnt work and if you are using android studio, try creating a new Map Activity(It's V3), complete res/values/google_maps_api.xml with the key and the map gonna work. 
[How to create google map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt0Fu.png)

Comment: What's the diiff BTW the native api v2 and the JavaScript api v3?